# Convert MySQL query using Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a question regarding a MySQL query. 
I would like to know how to create the same query using Laravel  QUERY Builder

```
SELECT count( * ) as total_record FROM `player_games` WHERE team_score <  rival_score
```

Thanks

Comment: just read laravel document.

Comment: https://laravel-news.com/convert-sql-laravel-builder-orator

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
$query = "SELECT count( * ) as total_record FROM `player_games` WHERE team_score <  rival_score";

$count = \DB::select(\DB::raw($query));
```

secod way

```
DB::table('player_games')->where('team_score','<','rival_score')->count();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks...the result is [{"total_record":1}]...I would like to have 1 instead.

Comment: @user10087184 try second way

Answer (score 0):

```
$total_record = DB::table('player_games')->where('team_score', '<', 'rival_score')
                         ->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

in Laravel Query Builder you can write this:

```
$player_games = DB::table('player_games')->where('team_score','<', 'rival_score')->count();
```

---

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

Answer (score 0):

There's a subtle thing here that you need to be aware of:

```
DB::table('player_games')
     ->where('team_score','<',\DB::raw('`rival_score`'))
     ->count();
```

The reason why you need `\DB::raw` is because if you don't then the right-hand side of the where will be automatically assumed to be a value and be passed as a binding, however you need to pass it as a raw DB expression to indicate that it's actually a column name. The backticks are added because it's good to escape the column names.

Comment: There is a built-in to avoid the dirty hack with backticks (which is not DBMS agnostic by the way): `$query->whereColumn('left_column', '<', 'right_column')`